# Suggestion for a paraconsistent logic book

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

I recently read a book on propositional logic and came across the explosion principle. Later, I learned about how paraconsistent logic is able to work its way around it. I wanted to learn more about this topic but there is hardly any book accessible where I live, also the books that are available to be purchased are insanely priced. So, I am asking for few recommendation for an accessible book and might perhaps some other resources to study more about the topic.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy is a good place to start.

See [the chapter on paraconsistent logic.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/)